# How to stretch a table to full page height

Tags: css, html, scroll

Now this may be extremely simple, but I being new to HTML/CSS, can't figure it out. Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 275px;background: gray;overflow: scroll">
                    <div style="height: 1000px;width: 250px; background: green;" />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 620px;background: yellow;">
                    def
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,body,table
{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

What I want is to make this table stretch to full page height; and in case the contents of the left cell are larger than full page height, a simple scrollbar should appear in the left cell to let user scroll through them. But instead, my code makes the whole table larger and the inner scrollbar never appears to work.

Comment: Are you aware of your page & table is max-height: 500px?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change your styling a little bit:

```
<td style="width: 275px;background: gray;overflow: scroll; height: 100%">
   <div style="height: 100%;width: 250px; background: green;float: left" id="test" />
</td>
<td style="width: 620px;background: yellow;">
   def
</td>
```

and remove `max-height` like @Allan Kimmer Jensen mentioned in comment

```
html,body,table
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/z29hT/)

**UPDATE**

add ID to div and bit of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function elementHeight(element) {
            var height = 0;
            var body = window.document.body;
            if (window.innerHeight) {
                height = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
                height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
            } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
                height = body.clientHeight;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).style.height = height + "px";
        }
        elementHeight('test');
</script>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z29hT/3/)

Comment: Thanks. But the main issue is that the div in the left td is going to be of arbitrary size, so I can't set its height to 100%. It is besically a TreeView that will have large amount of data and I don't want the whole table to grow that large.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with css only, as you want div to be 100% screen height and with overflow. Use javascript to grab screen height and set it to that div.

Comment: I'm willing to do that. Can you plz post an example? Sorry, I'm a bit new to this web world. In my WinForms and WPF/SL world it is sooooooo easy to do.

Comment: Do you want it to be with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm not too sure about the pros and cons of each. This is an ASP.NET 4.0 project.